# How to copy a file from my Windows laptop to an Ubuntu server while using PuTTY?

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, scp

I have a remote server and I connect it via PuTTY software.
I've downloaded a file to my Downloads folder in my Windows OS laptop.
Now, I have to transfer this file to that remote server, using SCP Unix command.

Can someone bring me a clear and specified pattern or even an example of that command to my situation ?

Please help me, I've be working on it for a long time and can't solve the problem...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: AFAIK to copy a file *from* your Windows OS laptop using "SCP Unix command", you need to have an SSH server running under Windows. What you *can* do is copy it *to* the remote server [using the PuTTY `pscp` command](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/putty-manuals/0.68/Chapter5.html) - or, even easier, using [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php)

Comment: ... unless you install [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq) of course

Comment: At first, I really wanna thank you for your comment; Now, my question is - What the exact format of path the command is excepting ? ( - E.g. path like this "C:\Users\User\Documents\111.txt", it doesn't accept it.)

Comment: Sorry - that's really a Windows question not an Ubuntu one. IIRC you can copy the path from Windows Explorer by right clicking in the address bar and selecting "copy as text" or somesuch.

Comment: I have to type that command on Windows cmd or on PuTTY emulator for the remote server ?

Comment: ... in Windows cmd

Comment: Since you're asking about PuTTY on the Windows side of things, your question might find a better answer on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) which is another part of the StackExchange network geared towards Windows-related inquiries.

Comment: You may find this previous answer helpful [SSH scp between Ubuntu Server 12.04 and Windows failing - (prob syntax)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/354330/ssh-scp-between-ubuntu-server-12-04-and-windows-failing-prob-syntax/354388#354388) although note that you will need to swap the order of the remote and local arguments since you want to copy **from** local **to** remote

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you can use WinSCP. WinSCP is an open-source free SFTP client, FTP client Its main function is file transfer between a local and a remote computer. and integrates well with putty

[WIN SCP Download link](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php)

Step 1: Once you download the package, install it and open after installation.

Step 2: You will be prompted to add a new site. 
In the **red** marked box, enter the **IP** of the remote server, in the **blue** marked box, enter the **username** which you would have used to SSH to the server, in the **green** marked box, enter the same **password** used for SSH.

Step 3: By clicking on **Save** you can save these details for further use(i have saved a session **ttttttttttt** which appears on the top left-hand side)

Step 4: Finally, click on the button marked in the purple box.

[image: screenshot of winscp]