# Transfer from local Windows machine to remote Linux server

Tags: windows, transfer, scp

Sometimes I cannot access my work server from FileZilla (which I use to transfer files from my Windows laptop). I tried to transfer files from the command line using:

```
scp -P myport D:\Users\myname\test.txt myname@serverIP:/data/myname
```

But I get this error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname d: Temporary failure in name resolution
Host key verification failed.
```

Other colleagues (who use Linux) had trouble connecting, and for them removing `/home/myname/.ssh/known_hosts` solved the problem. I cannot find any `known_hosts` file in Windows. I only have a `D:/Users/myname/.ssh` folder with the `id_rsa`.
I also tried

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa @serverIP
```

but I get

```
getaddrinfo @serverIP: Name or service not known
```

What is preventing me from copying from Windows to my server? I am also not very experienced so it could be just some typo or formatting problem. I am doing all of this inside a MobaXterm (an interface to connect to a server) session on my server, which is probably the problem. Shall I follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/354330/ssh-scp-between-ubuntu-server-12-04-and-windows-failing-prob-syntax) instead?

**EDIT:** my Windows directory is D:/, not C:/

Comment: IMHO yes the situation you describe sounds exactly like the linked question - I find WinSCP easiest

Comment: `Temporary failure in name resolution` suggests a DNS issue in resolving a hostname - are you connecting to the server by a hostname or an IP?

Comment: @steeldriver I'll try it then.
dom1310df I'm using an IP, but I get the same problem with the hostname.

Comment: I don't think this is an Ubuntu issue. Check your DNS.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that scp uses `:` as a separator between remote hostname and the filename.  So it is trying to contact host "D" when this is a local file.

Instead, change your current drive to D: (or change to the full directory and don't include the path at all) and just copy the file without the D:

Also, to get scp to work, you need to be keenly aware of what is local and what is remote.  For this to work at all, you need to run this in a local shell, not a remote shell.   You can't run this command on the server and expect it to be able to reach out and touch your local non-server desktop or laptop.  Also the windows machine must be local because likely you are running ssh/scp there and not sshd under windows.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, the error came when I was copying a file from D: (and not C:), that was a typo However, when I tried to change the full directory (`cd D:/Users/myname`) it didn't work (I guess because I am trying to set my Windows directory on my server). But as soon as I tried without the D:, I could add my server to the list of known hosts. Still, I cannot copy, and I get a `/Users/myname/test.txt` doesn't exist (I guess because it exists only on my Windows and if I am not specifying D: it searches for it in my `/Users/myname/` on the server)...

Comment: Windows remembers current drive and separately current directory for each drive.  You'll have to play with this to get it to work.  Running scp alone without changing drive/directory will be awkward.

Comment: @user10489 they will **never** get this to work in the way they are trying, since they are already logged on to the remote system via SSH (mobaxterm) but are issuing an scp command that expects the Windows box to be their local filesystem

Comment: steeldriver: good point.  Added.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I'll look into WinSCP.